# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined после использования bootstrap.min.js

Tags: jquery, joomla3, bootstrap4

Не могу понять в чем дело. на странице Списка контактов в joomla 3 не работает bootsrap.min.js (bootstrap-4.0.0) и jquery.min.js 3.3.1, тогда как на остальных страницах все работает. к js обращаются 2 модуля - меню и слайдер, но они есть на любой странице.

[image: выводимые ошибки]

Страница конкретного контакта открывается нормально. Использую  только bootsrap.min.js без map, так как  минифицировала bootstrap сама, были изменения.
Использую только это:

[image: Используемые js]

ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

все возможные подключения к странице:

```
<title>Список сотрудников «Кәсіптік және техникалық оқыту» кафедрасы</title>
<link href="/joomla3/index.php/kz/spisok-sotrudnikov-k-siptik-zh-ne-tekhnikaly-o-ytu-kafedrasy?format=feed&amp;type=rss" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" />
<link href="/joomla3/index.php/kz/spisok-sotrudnikov-k-siptik-zh-ne-tekhnikaly-o-ytu-kafedrasy?format=feed&amp;type=atom" rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 1.0" />
<link href="/joomla3/templates/mywkau/css/bootstrap.css?a44c081ffd8a1c5d1ae9cd19bd8f6076" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/joomla3/templates/mywkau/css/font-awesome.min.css?a44c081ffd8a1c5d1ae9cd19bd8f6076" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/joomla3/templates/mywkau/css/main.css?a44c081ffd8a1c5d1ae9cd19bd8f6076" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/joomla3/modules/mod_joomspirit_slider/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
<link href="/joomla3/media/mod_falang/css/template.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://10.10.216.13/joomla3/modules/mod_pixsearch/media/css/mod_pixsearch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="application/json" class="joomla-script-options new">{"csrf.token":"33ccc4a841b8860f1045a9239365f633","system.paths":{"root":"\/joomla3","base":"\/joomla3"}}</script>
<script src="/joomla3/media/system/js/core.js?a44c081ffd8a1c5d1ae9cd19bd8f6076"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="/joomla3/media/jui/js/html5.js?a44c081ffd8a1c5d1ae9cd19bd8f6076"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="/joomla3/templates/mywkau/js/popper.min.js?a44c081ffd8a1c5d1ae9cd19bd8f6076"></script>
<script src="/joomla3/templates/mywkau/js/bootstrap.min.js?a44c081ffd8a1c5d1ae9cd19bd8f6076"></script>
<script src="/joomla3/templates/mywkau/js/main.js?a44c081ffd8a1c5d1ae9cd19bd8f6076"></script>
<script src="http://10.10.216.13/joomla3/modules/mod_pixsearch/media/js/pixsearch.js"></script>
<script src="http://10.10.216.13/joomla3/modules/mod_pixsearch/media/js/gpixsearch/gpixsearch.nocache.js"></script>
<script>
<link rel="alternate" href="http://10.10.216.13/joomla3/index.php/kz/spisok-sotrudnikov-k-siptik-zh-ne-tekhnikaly-o-ytu-kafedrasy" hreflang="kz" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://10.10.216.13/joomla3/index.php/kz/spisok-sotrudnikov-k-siptik-zh-ne-tekhnikaly-o-ytu-kafedrasy"  hreflang="x-default" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://10.10.216.13/joomla3/index.php/en/spisok-sotrudnikov-k-siptik-zh-ne-tekhnikaly-o-ytu-kafedrasy" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://10.10.216.13/joomla3/index.php/ru/spisok-sotrudnikov-k-siptik-zh-ne-tekhnikaly-o-ytu-kafedrasy" hreflang="ru" />
```

собственный код из main.js

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 var PrevNext;
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() 
 {
  //  alert($('.NotfixedTop').offset().top);
  if (jQuery('section.menues').hasClass('NotfixedTop') )
  {
      if (jQuery(window).scrollTop()>= jQuery('.NotfixedTop').offset().top)
    {
             jQuery('.NotfixedTop').each(function (){ 
                                              jQuery(this).addClass( "fixed-top");
                                         jQuery(this).removeClass( "NotfixedTop");
                                              });
   
       } 
  }
  if (jQuery('section.menues').hasClass('fixed-top') )
   {
     if ( jQuery(window).scrollTop()<= 18) 
         {
       jQuery('.fixed-top').each(function (){ 
                                         jQuery(this).addClass( "NotfixedTop");
              jQuery(this).removeClass( "fixed-top");
                                             }); 
      } 
   }

 });
 
 jQuery('#navbarSupportedContent2 .dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
  if (jQuery(this).parent().hasClass('dropdown-submenu')) {
   
  // alert('dropdown-submenu');
  }
  else {
   //alert(jQuery(this).offset().left/jQuery(window).width());
   if (jQuery(this).offset().left/jQuery(window).width()>0.55) {
    jQuery(this).next().css({"left":"-360px"})
   }
   
   
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: посмотрела внимательно список подключенных модулей  - не подключена jquery, на других страницах все норм. это следствие этой  ошибки или ее причина?

Answer (score 0):

нашла решение 
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=893641

при формировании index.php  была пропущена строка

JHtml::_('jquery.framework');